# Html CSS form not showing radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I want to create a registration form. I put the HTML radio button code but however, it is not showing the radio buttons. 
I used the "inspect element" in google chrome developer tools but couldn't resolve the problem.

I have highlighted the error-prone area. Rest areas are working fine.

Project code is given. I am new to Front End, Kindly help.

```js
$('.form').find('input').on('keyup blur focus', function(e) {

  var $this = $(this),
    label = $this.prev('label');

  if (e.type === 'keyup') {
    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
      label.addClass('active highlight');
    }
  } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
      label.removeClass('highlight');
    }
  } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('highlight');
    } else if ($this.val() !== '') {
      label.addClass('highlight');
    }
  }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: url(../background.jpg);
  /*font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-size: cover;
}

.user {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: calc(50%-50px);
  right: -170px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(39, 153, 219);
  transition: .5s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
  transition: .5s ease;
  position: relative;
}

.form:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(18, 18, 18, 1.00);
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5px 20px 0;
}

.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #0C0E67;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #0C0E67;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-group .active a {
  background: #1316FA;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content>div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}


/*label {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 13px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}
label .req {
  margin: 2px;
  color: red;
}*/

label.active {
  transform: translateY(50px);
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 0px;
}

label.active .req {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
  color: #000;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #000;
}

.field-wrap input {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.field-wrap i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -5px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: silver;
}

.field-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.top-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.top-row>div {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.top-row>div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

#sp1 {}

.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 50rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: rgb(54, 57, 221);
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  background: #1316FA;
}

.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

fieldset.date {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

fieldset.date legend {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: .25em;
  font-size: 100%;
}

fieldset.date label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20em;
  left: -200em;
}

fieldset.date select {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">

    <ul class="tab-group">
      <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="signup">

        <form action="" method="post">


          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required autocomplete="off" />
            <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
          </div>


          <div class="field-wrap">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required autocomplete="off" />
            <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">

            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required autocomplete="off" />
            <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required autocomplete="off" />
            <i class="fa fa-lock icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" required autocomplete="off" />
            <i class="fa fa-phone icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required autocomplete="off" />
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker icon"></i>
          </div>

          <!--Problem Region-->

          Gender<br>
          <div>

            <input type="radio" name="gender">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" />Female

          </div>


          <fieldset class="date">
            <legend>Birthday </legend>
            <label for="month_start">Month</label>
            <select id="month_start" name="month_start" />
            <option>January</option>
            <option>February</option>
            <option>March</option>
            <option>April</option>
            <option>May</option>
            <option>June</option>
            <option>July</option>
            <option>August</option>
            <option>September</option>
            <option>October</option>
            <option>November</option>
            <option>December</option>
            </select> -
            <label for="day_start">Day</label>
            <select id="day_start" name="day_start" />
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>19</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>21</option>
            <option>22</option>
            <option>23</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>25</option>
            <option>26</option>
            <option>27</option>
            <option>28</option>
            <option>29</option>
            <option>30</option>
            <option>31</option>
            </select> -
            <label for="year_start">Year</label>
            <select id="year_start" name="year_start" />
            <option>2009</option>
            <option>2010</option>
            <option>2011</option>
            <option>2012</option>
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2014</option>
            <option>2015</option>
            <option>2016</option>
            <option>2017</option>
            <option>2018</option>
            </select>
          </fieldset>

          <!--Error RegionEnds-->

          <button type="submit" class="button button-block" />Register </button>

        </form>

      </div>

      <div id="login">

        <img src="./user.png" class="user">

        <form action="/" method="post">

          <div class="field-wrap">

            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required autocomplete="off" />
            <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required autocomplete="off" />
            <i class="fa fa-lock icon"></i>
          </div>

          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

          <button class="button button-block" />Log In</button>

        </form>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- tab-content -->

  </div>
  <!-- /form -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see the radio buttons, they're overlapping the labels.

Comment: You should put `<label>` around the buttons and text so the user can click on the word instead of having to hit the button exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `height` property in CSS using the `input` selector is throwing off your markup and causing the radio buttons to expand far past the point you can see them. I would suggest to be more specific with your selectors. Here's code to give you an idea of what's happening and how to fix it:

```js
$('.form').find('input').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
  
  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.prev('label');

   if (e.type === 'keyup') {
   if ($this.val() === '') {
          label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
          label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
     if( $this.val() === '' ) {
      label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
   } else {
      label.removeClass('highlight');   
   }   
    } else if (e.type === 'focus') {
      
      if( $this.val() === '' ) {
      label.removeClass('highlight'); 
   } 
      else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
      label.addClass('highlight');
   }
    }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
  
  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
  
  $(target).fadeIn(600);
  
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}


body {
  background:url(../background.jpg);
  /*font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-size:cover;
}
.user{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
top: -10px;
left: calc(50%-50px);
right: -170px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(39, 153, 219);
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
  transition: .5s ease;
  position: relative;
  
}

.form:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(18,18,18,1.00);
 }

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5px 20px 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #0C0E67;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #0C0E67;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background:#1316FA;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

/*label {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 13px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}
label .req {
  margin: 2px;
  color: red;
}*/

label.active {
  transform: translateY(50px);
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 0px;
}
label.active .req {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
  color: #000;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
[type="radio"] {
height: 10px;
}
input {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}
input:focus{
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #000;
}

.field-wrap input{
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.field-wrap i{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: -5px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: silver;
}
.field-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  
}

.top-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.top-row > div {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.top-row > div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

#sp1{
  
}
.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px;

  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 50rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: rgb(54, 57, 221);
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  background: #1316FA;
}

.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
fieldset.date { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  padding-left: 20px; 
  padding-bottom: .5em; 
  display: block; 
  border: none; 
} 
fieldset.date legend { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin-top: .25em; 
  font-size: 100%; 
} 


fieldset.date label { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: -20em; 
  left: -200em; 
} 

fieldset.date select { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
font-size: 100%; 
display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
      
      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">   
        
          <form action="" method="post">
          
         
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required autocomplete="off" />
              <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
            </div>
        
            
          <div class="field-wrap">
              
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            
            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-lock icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
              <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" required autocomplete="off"/>
              <i class="fa fa-phone icon"></i>
            </div>
          
            <div class="field-wrap">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required autocomplete="off"/>
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker icon"></i>
              </div>

<!--Problem Region-->

              Gender<br>
              <div>
                    
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" >Male
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" />Female
            
                </div>


                <fieldset class="date"> 
                    <legend>Birthday </legend> 
                    <label for="month_start">Month</label> 
                    <select id="month_start" 
                            name="month_start" /> 
                      <option>January</option>       
                      <option>February</option>       
                      <option>March</option>       
                      <option>April</option>       
                      <option>May</option>       
                      <option>June</option>       
                      <option>July</option>       
                      <option>August</option>       
                      <option>September</option>       
                      <option>October</option>       
                      <option>November</option>       
                      <option>December</option>       
                    </select> - 
                    <label for="day_start">Day</label> 
                    <select id="day_start" 
                            name="day_start" /> 
                      <option>1</option>       
                      <option>2</option>       
                      <option>3</option>       
                      <option>4</option>       
                      <option>5</option>       
                      <option>6</option>       
                      <option>7</option>       
                      <option>8</option>       
                      <option>9</option>       
                      <option>10</option>       
                      <option>11</option>       
                      <option>12</option>       
                      <option>13</option>       
                      <option>14</option>       
                      <option>15</option>       
                      <option>16</option>       
                      <option>17</option>       
                      <option>18</option>       
                      <option>19</option>       
                      <option>20</option>       
                      <option>21</option>       
                      <option>22</option>       
                      <option>23</option>       
                      <option>24</option>       
                      <option>25</option>       
                      <option>26</option>       
                      <option>27</option>       
                      <option>28</option>       
                      <option>29</option>       
                      <option>30</option>       
                      <option>31</option>       
                    </select> - 
                    <label for="year_start">Year</label> 
                    <select id="year_start" 
                           name="year_start" /> 
                      <option>2009</option>       
                      <option>2010</option>       
                      <option>2011</option>       
                      <option>2012</option>       
                      <option>2013</option>       
                      <option>2014</option>       
                      <option>2015</option>       
                      <option>2016</option>       
                      <option>2017</option>       
                      <option>2018</option>       
                    </select> 
                  </fieldset> 

              <!--Error RegionEnds-->

          <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Register </button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div id="login">   
      
         <img src="./user.png" class="user">
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
           <div class="field-wrap">
            
            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-lock icon"></i>
          </div>
          
          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
          
          <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
      </div><!-- tab-content -->
      
</div> <!-- /form -->
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SunandanBhakat Glad I could help! To accept the answer be sure to hit the green checkmark on the side of it!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the height issue that was pointed out. It's a good idea to wrap the radio button inside a label tag. This makes it much easier for a user to interact with since its all clickable...

```
<label for="myRadioBtn">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadioBtn />
  <span>Label Text</span>
</label>
```